# How to extend HTMLAttributes with Storybook Docs + Typescript without creating a HUGE props table?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

We're building a React component library using Storybook 5.3.x and just converted to Typescript.  We are using `addon-docs` to show a table of available props for each component.

When creating a React component, the props table is generated from whatever type we define the props to be.

```js
const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {...}

// Generated props table will show all props in MyComponentProps
```

But using this, we can't use any native HTML attributes (like `id`) because they're not explicitly on `MyComponentProps` or `IntrinsicAttributes`.  In a normal React component, you can fix this by extending the relevant `HTMLAttributes` type

```js
const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => {...}

//or

interface MyComponentProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {...}
const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {...}
```

However by using this pattern, in the rendered Storybook docs, the props table documents **every single native attribute**, making it hundreds of lines long and exponentially increasing compile time.

How can we extend an element's available props to include native HTML attributes, but not create a huge props table?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Storybook (6) doesn't do this anymore. When props extend HTMLProps, only the props unique to the component are shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a webpack custom config in storybook, if you must use storybook v5:

```js
{
                loader: 'react-docgen-typescript-loader',
                options: {
                    shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true,
                    tsconfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json'),
                    propFilter: function (prop) {
                        if (prop.parent) {
                            // removes props that inherits from React or other packages (includes HTMLProps)
                            return !prop.parent.fileName.includes(
                                'node_modules'
                            );
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```